# bxslider working on Chrome and Firefox but not on IE10

Tags: bxslider

I've build a site and i'm using bxslider on the home page. The thing is, it works on Firefox and Chrome but it doesn't work properly on Internet Explorer (I'm using IE10).

Here is my code.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="includes/box/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/box/jquery.bxslider.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 

        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
          auto: true,
          autoControls: false,
          captions: false,
          speed: 5000,  

          mode: 'horizontal',  
        }); 
    });

<div id="slider">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li><img src="afbeeldingen/basiswebpakket.png" title="Basis webpakket - Statische websites" /></li>
        <li><img src="afbeeldingen/basiswebpakket.png" title="afbeelding2" /></li>
        <li><img src="afbeeldingen/basiswebpakket.png" title="afbeelding3" /></li>
    </ul>           
</div>
```

I dont understand why it is working on firefox and chrome but isn't working on IE. As you can see and the dots in the top right corner it is changing pictures but you can't see it on the page.

I hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to use the latest version of the jquery?
I can see that you are using v1.8.2, my site are using v1.9.0 and it works fine in IE10.

Comment: Thats not working to bad :(.. it is working in IE 8 and 9 but not in 10 :(

Comment: try this, uses ONLY jquery.bxslider.js and jquery.1.9.0++. And see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you loading both jquery 1.8.2 and 1.4.2? You should remove the second line:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking... Jquery versions was not the issue, I changed my document mode to `edge` (was previously `content="IE=7"`), that was my problem so check that out as well!

Make sure yours looks something similar to this...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
```